# Cause non-linear relation between intensity and photo-current

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics, power, photoelectric-effect

I wanted to investigate and validate the relationship between intensity and photo-current with a simple experimental setup. I expected a linear relationship based on the photo-diode's datasheet (I've added the link to the datasheet below).

The experimental setup consisted of the following parts: A 0.95 mW 630 nm laser, a polaroid to control the intensity of the laser, a 50/50 beam-splitter, which reflects a part of the beam towards a powermeter and transmits the other part towards the photo diode. We also used a lens to converge the laserbeam on the light sensitive area of the photo diode (picture below).

Based on our measurement data, we have obtained the following quadratic relationship, which does not make any sense to me, and I really don't know what could've gone wrong. Could it be the polaroid altering the relationship between the two quantities?

[image: The measured photocurrent as a function of the power. I expected this relationship to be at least somewhere near lineair but it is not even close to it.]

[image: The experimental setup we used for measuring the relationship between these quantity's.]

https://www.conrad.nl/nl/p/osram-fotodiode-to-39-820-nm-55-bpw-21-152977.html?WT.mc_id=affiliates:tradetracker:feed:152977&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=tradetracker&utm_campaign=316050&utm_content=ShopForward%20NL%20Shopping

Comment: Polarization affects the function of a beamsplitter. Try using neutral density filters.

Comment: @JohnDoty Could that explain the relationship that I've found? Do you have any idea how this affect the function of the beamsplitter?

Comment: @JohnDoty One would say that even though the beamsplitter and the polarization filter affect each other, the relationship between those two quantities would hold right? Since they are both affected by the same factors?

Comment: Can't say much without more details.

Comment: @JohnDoty Ah, what information do you want me to provide to you?

Comment: @JohnDoty I have used a ND filter instead of a polaroid and it worked! Thank you for the suggestion. Eventhough I did not gave you much details; do you still have a simple explanation as to why it would not work with a polaroid and a beamsplitter? Does it have to do with the reflected and tranmitted light?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/polref.html

Comment: @Masterrun80 the point John Doty is making is that the splitting ratio of your beam splitter is not exactly 50:50 and that it is in fact polarization dependent. This means the power out of one port does not necessarily equal the power out the other port and the ratio will change with polarization. I suggest making measurements where you measure the power using the power meter out of BOTH ports (by moving the power meter) as a function of polarization.

Comment: @Jagerber48 We thought about this too, but this should not affect the relation between the two quantities since they are both affected by a constant coefficient (the beam-split ratio)? This did matter when we wanted to calculate the responsivity and the quantum yield of the chip. So we indeed determined the mean ratio by changing the position of the ND filter a couple times, and used this to correct for the difference.

Comment: it certainly would not explain the relationship we found by our first measurements.

Comment: No I’m telling you the beam splitter ratio is NOT constant and that (despite the name of the optical component) the splitting ratio is slightly input polarization dependent. If you don’t believe me do the measurement and see.  Also post the part number for the beam splitter if you have it available and we can check the spec sheet.

Comment: Like for S polarization it might be 60:40 and for H polarization it might be 45:55 or something. (Made up numbers)

Comment: @Jagerber48 Ah, clear. I must not have understood your explanation then, but now I do. The previously found relation does confirm what you said. I also do not have the datasheet of the splitter, only the ratio. Also, I am curious as to what kind of graph would have formed if we continued the measurement with the polaroid and the splitter.

Comment: @Masterrun80 if you have a way to readout the rotation angle of the polarizer then you could (at fixed input power) measure and plot beamsplitter output 1 power vs output 2 power as a function of polarizer angle. This would be a measure of the polarization dependence of the beam splitting power ratio. If you can do this experiment I would love to see the data in your answer to this question :)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested I've used a ND filter instead of a polaroid to control the laser's intensity. This gave me the expected results, as shown in the figure below. As also said before: the beamsplitter affects the polarized light, in a for me, unknown way but it seems to change the relation between the two quantities (as shown in the figure below). If anyone has a detailed explanation, I'm very curious as to why it wouldn't work with a polaroid!

[image]

Comment: +1 for doing the experiment.

Comment: Another good experiment to make the abstractions real is just to walk around with polarizing glasses on, and cogitate on what you see.

Comment: Note that if this data was taken using the experiment pictured in the OP then your relationship between $P$ and $I$ will be skewed inasmuch as the splitting ratio of the beamsplitter is not 50:50 (as discussed in the comments). A better experiment would be to measure the current for each power and to measure the power right in front of the photo detector and use these for your data. Right now you're using the beamsplitter to pick off power and you're ASSUMING the splitting ratio is 50:50 but you haven't confirmed this. So your data may be skewed unless you calibrate the beamsplitter.

Comment: @Jagerber48 I did mention determining the mean ratio of the setup with the ND filter and the beamsplitter instead of the polaroid. We used this ratio to correct the data. the suggested experiment would probably have been better, but we wanted to keep the setup as static as possible. I am not sure whether you meant this?